# Program to check for special number not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def master():

    def sum_div(x):
        divisors = [1]
    for i in range(2, x):
        if (x % i)==0:
            divisors.append(i)
    return sum(divisors)




    def checker():
        if sum_div == x:
            return True
        else:
            return False




    def collector():
        sum_div(x)
        checker()
        collector()

x=int(input("enter a number here : "))
master()
```

this program should give me if the number is special it will print true if not print false but its not working some of this functions are not working how can I fix this code

Comment: can you tell when do you call a number special?

Comment: please edit to ensure no indentation problem.

Comment: @ashishsingh For example, 28 is a special number because its proper divisors are 1, 2, 4, 7 and 14, and 1+2+4+7+14=28. the sum of the divisors are equal to the number

Comment: The indentation in the pasted program seem to be completely out of whack. Also, you are defining `sum_div` as function (with unclear functionality), but then compare it to wht's supposed to be a user input (supposedly a number).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your code should look something like this:

```
def master(x):
    def sum_div(x):
        divisors = [1]
        for i in range(2, x):
            if (x % i)==0:
                divisors.append(i)
        return sum(divisors)

    def checker(sum_div,x):
        if sum_div == x:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def collector():
        sum=sum_div(x)
        return checker(sum,x)

    return collector()

x=int(input("enter a number here : "))
master(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

For me it was a bit hard to understand your code and follow your logic, partly because of the indentation.

Anyway, it seems like the mistake you repeated the most is that your forgot to pass arguments (like x) to the functions. Functions can not use params without receiving them earlier (or at least, this is more a correct programming style). Also you are calling to function the wrong why - function is like a method therefore the right syntax is `sum_div(x)` and not `sum_div`

I guess what you want is something like the following code:

```py
def sum_div(x):
    divisors = [1]
    for i in range(2, x):
        if (x % i)==0:
            divisors.append(i)
    return sum(divisors)

def checker(x):
    if sum_div(x) == x:
        return True
    else:
        return False

x=int(input("enter a number here : "))
print(checker(x))
```

We have two functions: checker and sum_div. Sum_div returns the sum of all divisors of x. notice it's receive x as an argument. checker is using `sum_div` to check if number is special.

You don't need any other function, was not sure why you need `master` and `collector`. If it is depends on me I will probably merge them together as well, I did not want to make further changes. If I had to write this code it will be something like this

```py
def is_special(x):
    divisors = [1]
    for i in range(2, x):
        if (x % i)==0:
            divisors.append(i)
    return sum(divisors)==x

x=int(input("enter a number here : "))
print(is_special(x))
```

only one function, nothing more. Technically you can improve it even more (the for loop) but that is unneeded for now.